# org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException How to define EXE path?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have this java class code in package ChromeBrowser (That I made)

```
package ChromeBrowser;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class LaunchChrome{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        String url = "<<<The URL I want to open>>>";
        WebDriver driver = setUp();
        launch(driver, url);
    }
    static void launch(WebDriver driver, String url) {
        driver.navigate().to(url);
    }
    static WebDriver setUp() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Selenium\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
        return driver;
    }
}
```

But when I run it, I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
```

Steps I've taken:

I have chrome installed.

I have downloaded the webdriver, and checked it is in C:\Selenium\chromedriver.exe

java jdk is in environment path

webdriver is in environment path, added in attempt to solve, didnt work

The code compiles and runs on my colleague's machine

Expected result:

Chrome browser opens at The URL I want to open.

Do I need to define the path to the chrome executable at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application?

Help me please thanks in advance.

EDIT:: I've tried most of the other stack overflow questions with the name of the error, but they haven't helped.

Comment: 1. You're using an `x86` machine. Please check if your chromedriver is 32-bit version of Chdromedriver. 
2. Your path to Chromedriver looks incorrect. Shouldn't this be `C:/Selenium/Chromedriver.exe` [Not sure about this ]

Answer (score -1):

I am not really sure what the issue is but you can try below suggestions-

> 1. System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:/Selenium/chromedriver.exe");
> 2. This could be a compatibility issue between the 'selenium', 'Chrome browser version' and 'chrome driver' version that you are using. If
>      you are using Selenium 2.53, then using chrome driver 2.25 should work
>      for you.
> 3. Download latest chrome driver from seleniumhq.org
> 4. Add 127.0.0.1 localhost to C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts.

Comment: The code works on my colleagues machine, which is set up with the same versions as everything, as said in the question. 127.0.0.1 already in hosts.

Answer (score -3):

Seems like there is some issue with creating session with Firefox. Try the following code and test using Chrome browser.

You need to download the executable driver from: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

```
public static void main(String[] args){
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
"/path/to/chromedriver");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver = new ChromeDriver();
//Puts an Implicit wait, Will wait for 10 seconds before throwing exception
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

//Launch website
driver.get("http://www.calculator.net/");

//Maximize the browser
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

or  Check the network settings (proxy, firewall, antivirus software), something is blocking
connections between selenium and the browser.

Comment: From the start of question, OP's focus is on ChromeDriver. Your initial debugging statement of session creation with Firefox is not correct.